# Where to find a the best narrators and producers to turn a good written work into a good audiobook

Tags: characters, publisher, audiobook

It seems that, in a similar way to movies, there is no waranty that a good book will be turned into a good audiobook. I've realised that after listening to some of the best sellers books recorded as unabridged audiobooks. In particular in The Caves of Steel by Isaac Asimov narated by William Dufris, the female voices are so awful, that I can't belive I finally finished the entire audiobook.

Looking for the best narrators, I stumbled with a couple of web sites that list the so called "Golden Voice" narrators. Maybe an equivalent to the "Academy Awards" for audiobooks.

The sites are [this one](http://www.apartmenttherapy.com/the-best-narrated-audio-books-167299) and [this one](http://www.audiofilemagazine.com/gvpages/short_profile.shtml).

[This](http://www.thepassivevoice.com/12/2011/why-do-audiobooks-suck/) other post was the reason why I choose to post the question here, since It may be of interest to some writers.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it may not be of importance to the writing domain.

Comment: This seems a few steps removed from writing, but I do see the relation. Thoughts, people?

Comment: My thoughts being that irrespective of the awards that are given to the narrators for books, it does not have any impact on writing. Of course it might be a wrong opinion too.

Comment: I think I agree

Comment: I *think* that this question is analogous to creating cover art or bookbinding or handwriting - related to writing, but not relevant to writing itself.

Comment: Ok, I think the consensus here is to close the question. Closing.

Comment: I think we'd accept questions about _attaching audiobook projects to a writing project_, but not pure audio/narration questions. (e.g., if somebody asked, "How do I know whether a prospective narrator is any good for my project," then I think the question would be appropriate, and rewards/recognition could be mentioned in the answers. Whereas "What awards exist for voice actors" seems like a voice acting question, not a writing/publishing question.

Comment: Thank you guys, I've edited my question considering your suggestions.

Comment: @rraallvv - I'm sorry, but I think the question is now about producing an audiobook, and is still not about writing.

Comment: Have raised this question on meta: [Audiobooks - on-topic here?](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/q/791/26)

Comment: We've been discussing this question, but IMHO it still isn't working. It's turned into a "where do I find..." question, which don't really work well on SE - it's a list/recommendation hybrid, and I'm not eager to have those. The other element here is the "awards for narrators" part, which was the original question, but IMHO it really doesn't fit here - asking "I want to make an audiobook, what awards are there in the genre?" sounds to me like asking "I want to produce my own movie, is hiring Academy Award-winning actors a good idea?" As written, if you don't know, you can't afford 'em.

Comment: My recommendation is: don't try to force this one into the format. Do you have a _problem to be solved_? Ask us that. You can try and create one less naturally, but that doesn't always work -  and that's perfectly fine.

Comment: @Standback I quite don't understand what you mean by "one less naturally", but yes, it is not for hiring, at least not in the near future, the question was mostly out of curiosity, and also to have an idea of what a good narrator can do for an audio book.

Comment: Reopening this, as per [discussion in meta](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/q/791/26).

Answer (score 1):

The "Audies" are pretty close: http://www.theaudies.com